# Using python for google search?

Tags: python, search

If I have a variable, lets say, favorite singer, I want to open the web browser and search for that singer. I was planning to use the following code to open Google, but how can I make the users input become the actual search itself?

```
webbrowser.open('www.google.com')
```

Comment: I tried the code from that link and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

To pre-populate the searchbox, use:

```
import webbrowser
from urllib import urlencode

webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com/?' + urlencode({'q': 'the quick brown fox'}))
```

Comment: @Haidro you spotted my deliberate mistake - well done

Comment: Thanks Jon. I want to use GPS coordinates and put them into google maps. So how would I do that? Here is some code (which doesn't work)

webbrowser.open('www.google.com/maps/',longitude_ref)

I have longitude_ref stored as a variable, but I want to use it to search.

Comment: @user2519572 Using a comma will add a space. Simply, use `+`. Or even `.format()`

Comment: @user2519572 you'll need to find the right url from experimenting with your browser, and then opening that...